# How to make a plot from my array of points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = -0.5*x*(x - 4);
h = 0.1;
Lina = {}
Dota[support_] = 
  {{1, 0, h}, {0, 1, f[support - 1  + h] - f[support - 1]}, {0, 0, 1}} . Warcraft;
Warcraft = {{0}, {f[0]}, {1}};
Dota[0] = {{0}, {0}, {f[0]}};
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, 
  AppendTo[Lina, Part[Dota[1], 1 ;; 2]]; 
  Warcraft = Dota[1];]
Print [Lina]
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4}], ListPlot[Lina]]
```

The above is my code. I want to plot points from the array `Lina`. 
I have them in this form (from my loop):

> `{{{0.1}, {0.195}}, {{0.2}, {0.39}}, {{0.3}, {0.585}}, {{0.4}, {0.78}}, 
>   {{0.5}, {0.975}}, {{0.6}, {1.17}}, {{0.7}, {1.365}}, {{0.8}, {1.56}}, 
>   {{0.9}, {1.755}}}`

How can I do that?

Comment: You have to `Append` a row to `Lina` . Use `Flatten` like `AppendTo[Lina, Flatten@Part[Dota[1], 1 ;; 2]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps, how can i mark this answer as solution? (best answer?)

Comment: You cannot accept comments as answers, you can  only vote them up.  You can only accept answers submitted with the check mark to the left.

Comment: `ListPlot[Catenate /@ Lina]` maybe you want.

Comment: its a comment @Proximus. So you can't mark it as answer. I am glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

So, Lina is equal to the list,

`{{{0.1}, {0.195}}, {{0.2}, {0.39}}, {{0.3}, {0.585}}, {{0.4}, {0.78}}, 
  {{0.5}, {0.975}}, {{0.6}, {1.17}}, {{0.7}, {1.365}}, {{0.8}, {1.56}}, 
  {{0.9}, {1.755}}}`

**Try this:**

```
ListPlot[Map[Flatten[#, 1] &, Lina ]]
```

And it should generate this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I post this to illustrate an alternative to `For` loop (one of the advantages of Mathematica). I may have misunderstood the aim, so apologies for any errors. The following aims to emulate the OP result.

I have changed variable names to lowercase. `Dota` is not required. The loop codes a recursion:

```
f[x_] = -0.5*x*(x - 4);
warcraft = {{0}, {f[0]}, {1}};
lina[support_, h_, n_] := 
 NestList[{{1, 0, h}, {0, 1, f[h + support - 1] - f[support - 1]}, {0,
       0, 1}}.# &, warcraft, n]
res = lina[1, 0.1, 9]
pl = Join @@@ res;
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4}, Epilog -> {Red, Line[pl[[All, {1, 2}]]]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Blue, Red}, {f[x], "Lina"}]]
```

So the result (`res`) is:

> {{{0}, {0.}, {1}}, {{0.1}, {0.195}, {1.}}, {{0.2}, {0.39}, {1.}}, \
>   {{0.3}, {0.585}, {1.}}, {{0.4}, {0.78}, {1.}}, {{0.5}, {0.975}, \
>   {1.}}, {{0.6}, {1.17}, {1.}}, {{0.7}, {1.365}, {1.}}, {{0.8}, {1.56},
>   \ {1.}}, {{0.9}, {1.755}, {1.}}}

The indexing could be changed (here 0 to 9 rather than 1 to 10).

The plot:

[image]